# How do i build a phonegap app for webapp?

Tags: phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, phonegap

I created a phonegap project in my machine and deployed it as a web app. when i browse it shows cordova is not defined. if i place the cordova.js inside the root folder then it throws some plugins are missin. anyone guide me how to host a webapp 
using phonegap project.

Answer (score 0):

Use this command to add the browser platform to your Cordova project,

```
cordova platform add browser
```

Now if you check inside your **platforms** directory there will be a new directory called **browser**.

Now run this, to get a browser compatible build.

```
cordova build android
```

Inside the "platforms > browser > www" directory you will find you web assets. You can host them on your server.